# Formula Excel: Search second last date with formula (relative position variable)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this objective: To bring with formula the penultimate date of each customer:

```
A                   B
Purchase date       Customer 
03/01/2018          5
03/02/2018          7
03/05/2018          7
** 03/06/2018 **    5 'target date
03/08/2018          7
** 03/12/2018 **    7 'target date
03/15/2018          5
03/15/2018          5
03/16/2018          7
```

On another sheet I have the list of clients without repeated and in the next column would be the results. I am faced with the inconvenience that the relative position is variable and I would not run a variant that I found of the formula SUMPRODUCT with LARGE because in the case of client 5 is the same result as the last date because the data is repeated, Ej ::

```
A           B
Customer    Penultima Date
1           01/01/1900
4           03/26/2018
5           03/15/2018
6           03/18/2018
7           03/12/2018
```

In B4 I have:

```
= SUMPRODUCT (LARGE (($ A $ 2: $ A $ 7231 = A4) * $ B $ 2: $ B $ 7231; 2))
```

But it launches me on 03/15/2018 and it should be on 03/06/2018

Please, gurus, a little help for this simple mortal. A cordial greeting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, your date formats are inconsistent.  Some of them are MDY and others are DMY.  The formula below depends on all of the dates being "real" dates and not text strings.

I used structured references, but you can easily change them to regular ranges:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(1/((Table1[Customer]=[@Customer])*Table1[Purchase date])),2)
```

Will return the penultimate matching date.  If there is no penultimate, the formula will return an error.

If you want to only count unique customer/date pairs, one way would be to

- Copy the original table to a new table
- Run the `Remove Duplicates` wizard on the new table, referencing both columns
- Apply the formula to this new table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ron, I have made the corrections on format days on the example. I notice that the formula stills giving 03/15/2018 instead of 03/06/2018 for the customer 5. Will there be a solution? Greetings.

Comment: Read the part of my answer from the formula to the end for one solution.